# Why I get this message when I open my wordpress site (how to solve it)?

Tags: php, wordpress, xampp, localhost, macos-big-sur

Undefined constant "‘FS_METHOD’" in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/wordpress/wp-config.php:98 Stack trace: #0 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/wordpress/wp-load.php(50): require_once() #1 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/wordpress/wp-login.php(12): require('/Applications/X...') #2 {main} thrown in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/wordpress/wp-config.php on line 98

Comment: You have something like `$array[FS_METHOD]` in your code, where it should read `$array['FS_METHOD']` (mind the quotes)

Comment: @LarsStegelitz Checked the code, there's nothing like that. :/

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. please take a moment and read this article https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask about how to asking questions also read this article https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example about how to ask a good question with minimum requirement.

Comment: please share with us your workout, code snippets, error logs, or any useful information to help answer your question.

Comment: please write a summarized title and put the rest of the explanation in the body. Secondly, please format your question with code fences to make the code readable. Goodluck 

Answer (score 1):

The error says that it is looking for the constant `FS_METHOD` and fails to find it. This is something you can set in your `wp-config.php` - I would try and set it as explained here: https://warptheme.com/wordpress-tutorials/update-wordpress-directly-without-using-ftp/

Kind regards,